# Chi-squared planned contrasts comparison adjustment problem

Tags: chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, contrasts

I have Groups A, B, and C. My hypotheses are:

1. Proportions of C are different from proportions of B (=independance)
2. Proportions of A are NOT different from proportions of B (=NO independance)

Results:

```
A: success = 0.085 n=50
B: Success = 0.167 n=50
C: Success = 0.380 n=50
```

If I do post-hoc contrasts using the `pairwise.prop.test()` in R, then I sacrifice power because there is no need to test C against A, especially given C against B is already significant.

The `pairwise.prop.test()` function provides a p-value adjustment such as Bonferroni, Holm or BH, BY (see R documentation for `p.adjust` in the `stats` package).

1. Which of these adjustments is most appropriate if choosing to do all post-hoc comparisons?
2. Would it be OK to conduct 2 chi-squared tests and test B against C as well as A against B and double the p-values?

Comment: This is just a variation of your previous question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21061/chi-squared-theory-question-testing-an-effect-and-null-effect-at-the-same-time.  Please combine them and indicate which one you would prefer to be closed.

Comment: I deleted the other posts. Also this is different because I am asking about plannned comparisons, not posthoc comparisons. Also, I am asking about right adjustment question 2 is about an alternative...